# Check multiple resources exist or not via SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I have multiple resources like `A, B, C`.

I want to know these resources exist in my database or not.

Here is a sample of query for one of them:

```py
ASK { <http://fkg.iust.ac.ir/resource/A> ?p  ?o }
```

This query returns `true` or `false`.

It's better to use one query, and I need to get 2 columns, `resource` & `existing`.

Here is my sample response:

```py
---------------------------------------------------
|        resource        |        existing        |
|========================|========================|
|           :A           |          true          |
|------------------------|------------------------|
|           :B           |          false         |
|------------------------|------------------------|
|           :C           |          true          |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I know `ASK` and `UNION`, but how can I put them together for this sample?

Comment: https://w.wiki/3yP

Comment: what's the `wdt:P361` in your sample? @StanislavKralin

Comment: `wdt:P361` is 'part of'.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time, find it with your help. @StanislavKralin

Comment: It's a really good question so I'll post an answer (the same as @StanislavKralin's basically, but not specific to Wikidata) for the benefit of future readers who may find this via Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query:

```
PREFIX : <http://fkg.iust.ac.ir/resource/>

SELECT ?resource (EXISTS { ?resource ?p ?o } AS ?existing) {
    VALUES ?resource { :A :B :C }
}
```

Test data:

```
<http://fkg.iust.ac.ir/resource/A> a _:dummy.
<http://fkg.iust.ac.ir/resource/C> a _:dummy.
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
| resource | existing |
=======================
| :A       | true     |
| :B       | false    |
| :C       | true     |
-----------------------
```

1. To get a tabular result, use `SELECT` instead of `ASK`
2. To get multiple solution for a known list of resources, use `VALUES`
3. `EXISTS` is like a mini-`ASK` query that can be embedded into expressions
4. Use the `SELECT (expression AS ?variable)` form to bind the result of the mini-`ASK` to the variable `?existing`
5. Caveat: The answer depends on what you mean by “a resource exists”. In an RDF graph, nodes are not created and deleted explicitly, but they exist simply by virtue of being used in a triple. The original `ASK` query as written checks whether there is any triple that has the node as its subject. For completeness, one may want to check for the object position as well:

   ```
   (EXISTS { ?resource ?p ?o } || EXISTS { ?s ?p ?resource })
   ```